# how to make stylegan using tensorflow pretrained models in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, pre-trained-model, stylegan

How to use python pretrained models in android .
I want to make similar cartoon effect project in android . What are the steps to get similar Cartoonify effects in android. Mostly projects are using python.
Below are the links referring to the project in python.

Cartoon - StyleGAN2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Oqpiaj0IUM

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s2XPNMwf6HDhrJ1FMwlW1jl-eQ2-_tlk?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

To deploy machine learning models in android , you can do following options:

```
 1.You can compress your models to smaller size Tensorflow lite files .
```

Reference.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert

https://github.com/margaretmz/Cartoonizer-with-TFLite

```
2. You can put your model in TF-Serving/Flask/Django/AWS and use GET/POST method through REST-API to send images and receive results accordingly.
```

Reference:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploy-ml-models-using-flask-as-rest-api-and-access-via-flutter-app-7ce63d5c1f3b

Comment: I will surely try this way of using it ..

Comment: Could you up vote the above answer if it helped! Thanks!